# Error in simulate.Arima with Nonzero Differencing Term and External Regressor

Tags: r, forecasting

When I try to simulate an Arima process with a unit root and external regressors, I get an error.  Reproducible code below:

```
y <- ts(c(3,5,10,13,4,15,13,17,20,24,26,27))
dummy <- data.frame(dummy=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
arima.1 <- arima(y, order=c(1,1,0), xreg=dummy)

future.dummy <- data.frame(dummy=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
n <- nrow(future.dummy)

sim.1 <- simulate(arima.1, nsim=n, xreg=future.dummy)
```

This produces the following error message:

```
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

I notice that when I set `future=FALSE` it works perfectly, but for my problem I want to be able to look at future simulated values.  I'd greatly any ideas as to what the problem might be. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered arima.sim() rather than simulate() ?

Comment: To my understanding, arima.sim() does not allow for external regressors.

Comment: Use `Arima()` instead of `arima()`.